# Prove point is in closure of set

Tags: general-topology, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Consider the set $M=\{ (1,x,x^2):x \in \mathbb{R}\}$.

We define $\text{cone}(M)$ as the conic hull of $M$, which admits conic combinations of its points, i.e. $\sum_i \lambda_i(1,x_i,x_i^2)\in M$ where $\lambda_i>=0\ \ \forall\ i$.

We can apparently see that $(0,0,1)\in\text{cl(cone(}M))$, the closure of the conic hull of $M$. The proof is simple:

$$
\begin{align}
(0,0,1)&= \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\Big(\dfrac{1}{x^2},\dfrac{1}{x},1\Big)\\
&=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\dfrac{1}{x^2}(1,x,x^2)
\end{align}.
$$

But I don't understand it. Can someone explain why the limit of $\dfrac{1}{x^2}\times(\text{an element of M})$ gives an element in the closure of $\text{cone}(M)$?

Comment: Well what you have is a sequence of elements of $Cone(M)$. In $\mathbb R^n$ that implies that the limit will be a in the cosure for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let x $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$ and $\lambda$ = $\frac{1}{x^2}$. Then p = $\lambda(1,x,x^2) = (\frac{1}{x^2},\frac{1}{x},1)$. Note that p $\in$ cone(M) $\forall$ x $\in \mathbb{R}$. Now take the limit as x goes to 0. This is a sequence of point in cone(M); thus the limit point is in cl(cone(M)).